# Concatenating strings in javascript results in missing period

Tags: javascript

I am trying to output an image dynamically but am stumbling on a bizarre issue where javascript deletes a period (full stop in British English). This means the output file location is incorrect and I get error 404.

Say:

```
var resultX = 10
```

Would you happen to know why:

```
'<img style="margin-left:30px;" src="Images/Icons/' + parseInt(resultX * 10) + '.png" />\'
```

outputs src:

```
https//localhost/Images/Icons/100png
```

and not

```
https//localhost/Images/Icons/100.png
```

The script works if I amend the last bit to `+ '..png" />\'`

**Edit**

I have removed the penultimate character `\` as suggested. The issue persists.

Comment: What's the backslash `\\` at the end for? Try removing it because it's normally used to escape special chars. Then replace the outer single quotes with backtickss. ```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Template literal: `<img style="margin-left:30px;" src="Images/Icons/${ parseInt(resultX * 10)}.png" />` Wrap in backticks ``` and the `${` replaces `'+` and the closing `}` replaces `+'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `\` at the end and your code is good enough. This is what i tried in chrome developer tools.

[image]

Comment: Hello Rishikesh. I don't understand what character you have removed.

Comment: Second last character. The \

Comment: That character allows you to jump to next line whilst outputting html. I have removed it, yet the problem persists.

Comment: Well, that's exactly I tried. Take a look at the image I attached. Can you try that?

Comment: I will advise him to start using ES6

Answer (score 3):

I think you made redundant "\" in

```
'<img style="margin-left:30px;" src="Images/Icons/' + parseInt(resultX * 10) + '.png" />\'
```

When I remove it

```
(function(){
        var resultX = 10;
        var str = '<img style="margin-left:30px;" src="Images/Icons/' + parseInt(resultX * 10) + '.png" />';
        $('.row').append(str);
    })();
```

it will show:

```
<img style="margin-left:30px;" src="Images/Icons/100.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using template literals. It worked for me.

```
var resultX = 10;
var output =`<img style="margin-left:30px;" src="Images/Icons/${resultX*10}.png"/>`
console.log(output)
```